# setState not returned from render when using Axios

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, axios

I'm using *axios* to get data from an endpoint. I'm trying to store this data inside the state of my React component, but I keep getting this error:

> Error: Results(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

I've struggled with many approaches: arrow functions etc., but without luck.

```
export default class Map extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        fillColor: {},
        selectedCounty: "",
        dbResponse: null,
    };
}

getCounty(e)  { 
    axios.get("/getWeatherData?county=" + e.target.id)
    .then((response) => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
            let fillColor = {...prevState.fillColor};
            fillColor[prevState.selectedCounty] = '#81AC8B';
            fillColor[e.target.id] = '#425957';
            const selectedCounty = e.target.id;
            const dbResponse = response.data; 
            return { dbResponse, selectedCounty, fillColor }; 
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Could not connect to the backend');
        console.log(error)
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div id="map">
            <svg>big svg file</svg>
                        
            {this.state.selectedCounty ? <Results/> : null}
        </div>

    )
}
```

I need to set the state using `prevState` in order to update the `fillColor` dictionary.
Should this be expected? Is there a workaround?

Comment: It looks like you don't even have a render method, so that'd be the first place to start

Comment: Your component appears to be missing the `render` method. Please confirm by include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your component code.

Comment: I do have a render method. I did not know it was relevant for this. Updated the question.

Comment: I think it has something to do with ```Results```.. I do not know how to pass an argument to it (```this.state.dbResponse```) in order to create a dynamic element based on it.

Comment: Ok, found the mistake: it was an error caused by ```Results```. I just replaced it with a method (i.e. ```this.displayData(this.state.dbResponse)```) and now everything works. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. @CertainPerformance @Drew Reese